# How to use HttpClients with third-party-libs?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, httpclient

#### Example initial situation:

Lets say I have a web api with dependency injection.
I normally would bind one HttpClient as singleton.

I think the HttpClient is regarded as mostly thread-safe.
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69950/single-instance-of-reusable-httpclient
(top answer - the three links)

But some member are not immutable like the 'BaseAddress'.

#### How should we use third-party-libs that need a HttpClient as dependency?'

The third-party-lib could use not thread-safe methods or change the not immutable members.

Should I create one client for every third-party-lib?
Is it 'save' to assume that the third-party-lib will use the HttpClient in the 'correct' way?

---

p.s second question asked on stackoverflow. Please don't kill me for asking.

Comment: It is not safe to assume anything about a third party code. And from my experience if something can go, it will go wrong eventually. My advice is: create a new client for the third party lib. It is not a heavy class anyway, so it won't affect performance (unless you spam millions of those clients), but it will be safer.

Comment: How about passing a IHttpClientFactory and follow [this pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#consumption-patterns) to get a HttpClient?

Maybe [Named clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#named-clients) is your solution.